# Remove fields from JSON Object

Tags: node-red

Hi can somebody help removing element from nested json array like this

```
{
"_id": "ProductionData1",
"_rev": "1-b4a160f5e13fab074d2fcc359e820d3f",
"topic": "",
"payload": {
    "plant Operating Time": "600",
    "plant stop": "10"
    }
}
```

Lets say I want to remove the object  "_id": "ProductionData1" "_rev": "1-b4a160f5e13fab074d2fcc359e820d3f" "topic": "", that should leave me with the following:

```
{
"payload": {
     "plant Operating Time": "600",
     "plant stop": "10"
     }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Also what you have shown is not a JSON array, it is a JSON Object

Answer (score 0):

The change node will allow you to remove key value pairs from a the `msg` object.

[image]

From the info sidebar:

> Set, change, delete or move properties of a message, flow context or
>   global context.
>
> The node can specify multiple rules that will be applied in turn.
>
> The available operations are:
>
> - Set - set a property. The value can be a variety of different types, or can be taken from an existing message or context property.
> - Change - search & replace parts of the property. If regular expressions are enabled, the replace with property can include capture
>     groups, for example $1. Replace will only change the type if there is
>     a complete match.
> - Delete - delete a property.
> - Move - move or rename a property.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your JSON through this function:

```
const jsonToTrim = {
   "_id": "ProductionData1",
   "_rev": "1-b4a160f5e13fab074d2fcc359e820d3f",
   "topic": "",
   "payload": {
      "plant Operating Time": "600",
      "plant stop": "0"
   }
};

function trimJSON(json, propsToRemove) {
    propsToRemove.forEach((propName) => {
      delete json[propName];
    });
}
// call the function 
trimJSON(jsonToTrim, ['_id', '_rev', 'topic']);
//inspect result
console.log(jsonToTrim);
```

This is the part that actually removes a property from your object:
    `delete json[propName];`
You can read more about delete [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

As far as the `json[propName]` is concerned it's an alternative way to writing json.propName and it allows us to have props names coming in dynamically (from an array).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Angular or Node

In Node or Angular to handle the response and use only particular variables from the object than try this.

```
let json ={
"_id": "ProductionData1",
"_rev": "1-b4a160f5e13fab074d2fcc359e820d3f",
"topic": "",
"payload": {
"plant Operating Time": "600",
"plant stop": "0"
}
```

Syntax to delete the element is angular is

```
    delete this.json['_rev']
    delete this.json['_id']
    delete this.json['topic']
```

The result after deleting this element you will get

```
{
"payload": {
"plant Operating Time": "600",
 "plant stop": "10"
}
```

Example [DEMO](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_property_object.asp)

Comment: Where is angular mentioned at all in the question?

Comment: This syntax can  also be used in NODEJS also . Either you provide a better solution rather than just pointing unnecessary comments

Comment: In that case your answer is just adding unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Okay , But if Syntax is  Same  . I have edited answer , surely it will not generate confusion now . 

Thanks